# multiply the object item by some random value and return as object

Tags: javascript

I have a array with objects like below:

```
[
  {
    current_temperature: "16.75°C"
    name: "London"
  }
  ...
]
```

I need to multiply this current temperature by some value and return in the same format as above.

I tried like below but its not working

```
this.data.map(item => {
   let temp = item['current_temperature'];
   Object.assign(this.data, {'current_temperature': temp.split('\u00B0')[0] * 32});
});
```

Comment: You want to assign to `item`, not to `this.data` (which is an array) And you might want to readd the °C

Comment: I want my final output with  temperature inside to be multiplied by 32. yes i have to add as well :) just noticed

Comment: You don't need `map` either, assuming you want to alter the original object (it sounds like you do)

Comment: you're using brackets notation wrong. It should be a dot notation in this case. So `item.current_temperature`

Comment: @Kevin.a in that case it's actually irrelevant, it would work in both cases, as far as I can tell.

Comment: can you help me plz?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const data = [
    {
       current_temperature: "16.75°C",
       name: "London"
    },
    {
        current_temperature: "10.75°C",
        name: "Tunis"
    }
 
]

const result = (multip) => data.map(res=> Object.assign({}, res, {current_temperature : res.current_temperature.split('\u00B0')[0] * multip +'°C'}));

console.log(result(10)) // multiplied by 10
console.log(result(32)) // multiplied by 32
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you wanted to transform the input data to a new array object containing the updated temperature data, you could use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with a `map()` callback that:

1. clones each mapped `item` via the spread operator
2. passes the `current_temperature` field to `Number.parseFloat()`, multiplies the result, and then re formats that back to the original temperature string format

This approach takes advantage of `Number.parseFloat()`'s behaviour where the input string will parse the first porition of the string that corresponds to a valid floating point number. Given your input string starts with "numeric characters", we can take advantage of the built-in behaviour of `Number.parseFloat()` to simplify the solution:

```js
const input = [{
    current_temperature: "16.75°C",
    name: "London"
  },
  {
    current_temperature: "12.00°C",
    name: "Auckland"
  }
]


const output = input.map(item => ({ ...item,
  /* Parse first floating part of current_temperature, multiply by 32, 
 format to string */
  current_temperature: `${ (Number.parseFloat(item.current_temperature) * 32).toFixed(2)}°C`
}));

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Why i getting Property 'map' does not exist on type '{}'. I am using vscode. there is a red line under map and when I hover on it I get that error.

Comment: It sound like you're calling `map()` on an `{}` Object, rather than an Array `[]` - can you please include some more of your code ?

Comment: const records = this.data;

        const output = records.map(item => ({
            ...item, current_temperature: `${(Number.parseFloat(item.current_temperature) * 32).toFixed(2)}°C`
        }));
        this.data = output;


My data format is same as yours.

Comment: Can you please add this before the `records.map(...)` and tell me what the console logs? `console.log('this.data is an array:', Array.isArray(this.data))`

Comment: this.data is an array: true

Comment: Very strange - are you able to send a link to your project on github?